# UIScrollView with storyboard using autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I can't find a working example on this. Every example I read doesn't mention storyboard, including [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html).

I don't want to add a subview programmatically, since I'm using a storyboard. Here is my view on the storyboard.

[image]

And here is the structure:

[image]

I was trying to follow release notes mixed approach and made contentView that has fixed width and height constraints, also leading and top constraints set to superview (scrollview in this case). Elements inside View have constraints reffering to View, and not the scrollview.

I also adde this code on viewcontroller `viewDidLoad`

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;    
CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 800);
[scrollView setContentSize:contentFrame.size];
```

All I get is not scrollable UIScrollView.

I'm struggling with this for weeks, is there a really working example out there?

EDIT:
Uploaded [sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30048160/AutolayoutScrollViewSample.zip) that demonstrates the issue. It also solves it! :)

Comment: Can you share a sample project (doesn't have to be your full project) that shows this problem? Why don't you want to go with a pure Auto Layout approach?

Comment: I don't understand it, I'd go for anything that works... I'll try to prepare sample project later

Comment: Edited question and uploades sample project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was ambigous content size width and height inside scroll view. The key is to not only pint trailing, leading, top and bottom constraints to scrollview but also make static scrollview height and width constraint.

Here is [sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30048160/AutolayoutScrollViewSample.zip) with solution